# How to remove apps that are remembered by App Store?

Tags: icloud, ios-appstore

Over the past few years, I have downloaded various apps onto my iPhone from the App Store.  I have noticed that the App Store remembers the apps that I have downloaded.  So, for instance: If I download an app and then delete it from my phone and go back into the App Store, the download icon is different (it doesn't say "+Get" like apps that I have never downloaded before, instead it will have an icon of a cloud with an arrow pointing downwards).

How to I get the App Store/iCloud to forget these programs?

Comment: Have you looked at this process with iOS 8? When you go to the purchased apps in the iTunes store on your mac or pc the option to hide isn't there. The x that appears in the top left of each icon in other versions isn't there in this one. Oddly, it is in music but not in apps. Has anyone figured out how to hide it in this version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will not be possible. You will see an cloud icon when you previously "purchased" an app. This will notify you that you could download the app without any costs.

It is not possible to delete those apps from your Apple ID.

If you don't want to see the cloud icon, you could sign out from the appstore via **settings** > **iTunes & App Store** > **sign out**. This will hide the cloud icon but you have to log in each time you want to download an app.

Answer (score 3):

You can delete the apps from your local iTunes, but they will show in your 'Purchased' view. If you don't want to see them any longer, you can simply right click and choose 'Hide'. They won't show in your Purchased view.

Comment: I want to make Apple totally forget I installed the App.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hide an app on an iPod 4, iPhone 4 or a newer model of either you just have to go to "purchased" in the App Store app and slide the app to the left, then click "hide".

Comment: I cannot slide an app in the "purchased" view.

Comment: No longer true for current iOS (10.2).